# Windows Easy Transfer does not allow me to backup

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-easy-transfer

When I run Windows Easy Transfer on my old Windows 8.1 computer, it tells me that I can use this program to transfer **to** this PC (and does not mention transferring **from** or backing up from this PC).

[image: Easy Transfer introduction]

If I click next, then it is either looking for an existing migrate file or tells me to run **Windows Easy Transfer** on the old computer

[image]

But this is the old computer, so how do I create the migrate file?

PS. My new machine and another Windows 8.1 machine in the office all behave the same way.

Comment: Windows Backup creates the migrate files.  What happens when you click `No`?

Comment: Don't think Windows 8.1 comes with 'Windows Backup'. If I click No, then the program just exits.

Comment: I promise you it does.  Windows Backup hasn't been removed from Windows 8.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I can dig up is that Microsoft discontinued support for it in Windows 8.1 (ref: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/security/windows-easy-transfer-win-81/882d4258-046d-4e39-9da3-efe7c4bb7cdd )

I've never used the tool myself but judging by the screenshot you can get pretty much the same or similar result by copying the c:/users folder onto portable storage (flash drive, external hard drive, etc) and then by dumping the contents of one user's folder into the new users folder. You could do this manually via drag and drop or use robocopy since you're on newer boxes. Note - if you want to retain some program settings you'll want to ensure you include hidden files for either method (this grabs the AppData folder).

Manual drag and drop:

- We'll say JohnDoe is our old account and our new one is JaneDoe, but you can move however you need to.
- Go to c:\ on the old machine, click the View tab up top and click "Hidden Items". Drag and drop the Users folder to your external storage.
- Unplug the storage from the old machine and connect to the new machine once transfer is complete
- Go to your new machine and open up c:\users\JaneDoe and open up the the files on your external storage to c:\Users\JohnDoe (the old account).
- Drag and drop the contents of JohnDoe's folder into JaneDoe's folder
- *If the JaneDoe account is brand new it's safe to overwrite everything when prompted. HOWEVER, if it's a not brand new, copy the AppData folder with caution - this WILL overwrite existing settings. You may have to dig further into that directory and get more selective with your copying if you need more granularity.